# Permission denied when trying to compile java files with another class from another directory

Tags: java, compiler-errors, file-permissions, permission-denied

For context, there are 2 java package files, Poligon.java and PersegiPanjang.java. I was trying to compile my second package but it said permission denied. I've checked the directory permission and it permitted all permission, but yet still denied when I tried to compile the package.

```
mylaptop@MacBook-Pro pert 3 % javac org/poligon/Poligon.java                             
mylaptop@MacBook-Pro pert 3 % javac -cp org/poligon;. org/bangundatar/PersegiPanjang.java
error: no source files
org/bangundatar/PersegiPanjang.java:1: permission denied: /Applications
org/bangundatar/PersegiPanjang.java:2: command not found: 3-inheritance.pdf
org/bangundatar/PersegiPanjang.java:3: command not found: 3-inheritance.pdf
org/bangundatar/PersegiPanjang.java:4: command not found: 3-inheritance.pdf
org/bangundatar/PersegiPanjang.java:5: permission denied: org/
org/bangundatar/PersegiPanjang.java:7: command not found: package
org/bangundatar/PersegiPanjang.java:9: command not found: import
org/bangundatar/PersegiPanjang.java:11: command not found: public
org/bangundatar/PersegiPanjang.java:private:12: not valid in this context: panjang,lebar
double=''
```

**Poligon.java** is located in "/Users/username/Desktop/Matkul/smt 4/pbo/prak/pert 3/org/poligon".

**PersegiPanjang.java** is located in "/Users/username/Desktop/Matkul/smt 4/pbo/prak/pert 3/org/bangundatar".

**Poligon.java**:

```
package org.poligon;

public class Poligon{
    protected int jumlahSisi;

    public int getJumlahSisi(){
        return this.jumlahSisi;
    }
}
```

**PersegiPanjang.java**:

```
package org.bangundatar;

import org.poligon.Poligon;

public class PersegiPanjang extends Poligon{
    private double panjang,lebar;

    public PersegiPanjang(double panjang, double lebar, int jumlahSisi){
        this.panjang = panjang;
        this.lebar = lebar;
        this.jumlahSisi = jumlahSisi;
    }

    public double hitungLuas(){
        return panjang * lebar;
    }

    public void printInfo(){
        System.out.println("Bangun Persegi Panjang bersisi         "+this.getJumlahSisi());
    }
}
```

I'm expecting it to be successfully compiled without any denied permission.[This is the file permission access information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bg6dg.png)

Comment: [Please never post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). They are not searchable, we cannot copy-paste... Always copy-paste the text and format it properly.
The path separator `;` is foreign to *your* OS. It should be `:` Please paste from Terminal in future. Had you done that, I would have posted the full and correct command instead of describing what it should be

Comment: Hey, just changed it to code blocks. Let me try your advice, and I will let you know ASAP! Thanks in advance!

Comment: HEY IT WORKED! Thank you so much. It was my college practicum assignment. My practicum assistant was using windows so he doesn't really know what to do in Mac OS and me either :(. You just saved my assignment! Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong guide; you are using one for windows, which means you are now using the wrong java path separator, which means this command is parsed differently.

> `javac -cp org/poligon;. org/bangundatar/PersegiPanjang.java`

**on the windows operating system**, `:` is the separator for drive letters, so it cannot be used to separate paths, so **on windows**, `;` is used. But in  **virtually all command line shells (Except windows's)**, `;` is the command separator. So, `:` is used.  The above, when you type that into a terminal, means bash has a look at that and goes:

Right, you want me to first run:

```
javac -cp org/poligon
```

and then you want me to run:

```
. org/bangundatar/PersegiPanjang.java
```

And that is **exactly** what your output says is happening. The first line produces the error 'no source files'.

The second line takes some more explaining: Almost all shell applications (it's the app you are typing these commands into, the one with the white text in the black box) have a `source` command, which reads in any file you provide it, and executes it like a shell script: Just run every command in that text file as if you typed it on the command line yourself, directly. And most shells have a single `.` as an alias for it.

So, `. org/bangundatar/PersegiPanjang.java` is identical to opening that java file, selecting all of it, copying it to the clipboard, going to your terminal, and pasting it all. Which results in a bevy of errors, as java, obviously, isn't command line speak.

The fix? Just replace that `;` with `:`. More general, you should *always* put java path args in single quotes, because if your shell escapes or otherwise processes it, it's never going to do what you want. `javac -cp 'org/poligon:.' org/bangundatar/*.java` is the command you want to type.

Comment: Yeah thanks, It worked! I was following a guide from my practicum assistant (he's using Windows) and I don't know what to do either in Mac OS. Thank you so much!